# android camera must call twice

Tags: android, camera, android-debug

I have an `Android` app about camera, the problem code like:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
mIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(mIntent, REQ_FROM_ALBUN);
```

And then in the `onActivityResult`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TestRolateAnimActivity.this, Camera.class);
intent.putExtra("newway", "albun");
intent.setData(uri);startActivity(intent);
```

And I must click the image twice than it will show in `Camera Activity`. It puzzled me for a long time.

So I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I have formatted your code on this one, but please try to format your code in the future.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Why must the user click the image twice? One click is to choose from gallery for `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but what is the context for second click?  Maybe, you can simply skip the first `Intent`?

Comment: Thank you.I mean when i click the button of camera,i want to jump to another activity,but i must click twice the camera button and i will succse.But i still do not know how to skip the first Intent,can you teach me how to do?